# Bypass the controller on a 2-wire multi function LED string

Tags: microcontroller, led

I have a halloween LED light decoration that I would like to simply turn on and show a solid light color whenever it has power, however it comes with a switch that goes through multiple flashing modes. At the moment, when the controller receives power it always defaults to the lights being off, then I have to press the switch 8 times to get it to be on a solid color.

I believe it is a [2-Wire LED String Type 2 mentioned in this article](https://auschristmaslighting.com/wiki/Controlling-2-wire-Multi-Function-LED-Strings), but I am unsure. I can't find a similar circuit board to this online.

I don't mind if the controller itself is trashed, what connections can I jump to get the lights to always be on, and not flashing whenever it has power?

[image: controller image]

Comment: What voltage does it use? And what color are the leds you want solid on? The led string you link to is made of alternating direction leds so if you want all of them on, which means flashing at a rate fast enough you can't tell they are flashing, you would need to replace the controller with your own plus supporting parts. Alternatively you could add a microcontroller that just does the 8 button presses for you. Much simpler.

Comment: 3 AA batteries so 4.5v. Orange and purple, but the caps are colored so it is possible they are actually both white. I was afraid that would be the answer. I considered automating the button presses but it feels janky to me, and I'd rather not spend more money on hardware just for this light if it can be helped.